# How can i insert multiple images Laravel / VUE / Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

How can i upload multiple images instead of one, uploading one image works now this is what i am using. I have uploaded many images with Laravel and blade, but with vue im not sure on how to achieve this

Vue Template

```
<input type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange" multiple />
```

In Vue Script

```
 onImageChange(e) {
      // console.log(e.target.files[0]);
      this.image = e.target.files[0];
    },

  SubmitProducts(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const config = {
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      };
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", this.image);
      axios
        .post("/admin/products", formData, config)
        .then((result) => {
          var v = this;
          v.showalert = true;
          setTimeout(function () {
            v.showalert = false;
          }, 3000);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

ProductController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            $image      = $request->file('image');
            $fileName   = 'products' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('uploads')->put($fileName, file_get_contents($image));
            $product->image = $fileName;
            $product->save();

            DB::commit();

            return response()->json('Product successfully inserted');
        }
```

Comment: Instead of creating one variable `this.image = e.target.files[0];` couldn't you just loop through the `e.target.files` array? Like `this.images = e.target.files` and in the javascript below loop through the array, appending every image as a unique variable.

Comment: I did as you said, but it keeps giving TypeError: this.image.push is not a function" whenever i try to push it in an array,

Comment: Have you changed the variable as I wrote? Maybe it is `this.images` now and not `this.image` anymore? I changed to plural because it makes sense. Adjust your code accordingly, of course.